# backticks showing on the page

Tags: javascript, html, web

i was making a simple project that takes some books informations from an API and then shows them as `<li>` elements but the map function returns them with a back-tick shown as text, and it is displayed on the page

JS:

```
    booksArray.map((book, n) => {
            let {title} = book;
            let authors = getAuthorsArray(book)
            return `<li class="book-card" id=${n}>
                    <h2>${title}</h2>
                    <p>${authors}</p>
                </li>`
        }
    )
```

Comment: After map, join your result `booksArray.map((book, n) => {return ``}).join('')`

Comment: it worked! can you explain me why?

Comment: [@Mando](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17881542/mando), [@sachin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12681984/sachin) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73591307/backticks-showing-on-the-page#73591390) to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73591307/backticks-showing-on-the-page#comment129954346_73591307)

Comment: As I mentioned in the answer, map function returns an array and you were printing it as it is.
You were printing `<li>...</li>,<li>...</li>,<li>...</li>` instead of `<li>...</li><li>...</li><li>...</li>` so there was a comma after every </li>
When we joined it, it joined all the strings and made a big string without those commas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is not with your backticks but with the `booksArray.map` function.

1. Array.map always return an array separated by commas.
2. HTML will add commas as it is when you render an array of data.

To avoid this, just add `.join("")` at the end of map function.
Like this :

```
return booksArray.map((book, n) => {  
// Your return HTML logic  
})**.join("")**
```

Hope this helps!